# How can i get the order of parents using number of child data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the order of Users table on the basis of roles.. for example if user has three roles its comes first, then user of two roles comes and so on
her it is my query but it gives order to role table not parent table

```
$users = User::with(['roles'=>function($query){
        $query->orderBy('id','desc');
    }])->get();
    dd($users);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method and order the results

```
$users =  User::query()
    ->withCount([
        'roles as no_of_roles_for_user'
    ])
    ->orderByDesc('no_of_roles_for_user')
    ->get();
```